# Python way - Iterate array, check for element at index, append new string to array

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
Iterate a list
    if an element (string) does not have a '$' at the first position
        apply a '$'  and append the new value to the array
```

I'm trying something like:

```
  symbols = ['aol', 'goog', ...]
  (symbols.append('$'+val) if '$' != val[0] for val in symbols)
```

But I'm getting a syntax error. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to take a look at how [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) work.

Comment: Hello - OK, thanks for the resource. I'll give it a view and attempt again.

Comment: @s.bandara It's not really a good tag (pythonic is just a tag synonym for Python) - I don't think it would see enough usage to make doing that worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over a shallow copy of the list and check for `$` using `str.startswith()`:

```
In [81]: symbols = ['aol', 'goog','$foo','bar']

In [82]: for x in symbols[:]:
    if not x.startswith('$'):
        symbols.append('$'+x)
   ....:         

In [83]: symbols
Out[83]: ['aol', 'goog', '$foo', 'bar', '$aol', '$goog', '$bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do as Ashwini proposed or you may just comprehend the list and append with the existing list

```
symbols + [('' if e.startswith('$') else '$') + e for e in symbols]
```

It does what Ashwini proposed that but instead of appending to an exisiting list it comprehends a new list (which is comparably faster) and append to the exisiting list.

Answer (score 0):

```
symbols.extend('$' + s for s in symbols if s[:1] != '$')
```

This is similar to what others have posted but utilizes a slice (to function w/ the empty string) for conciseness instead of 'startswith' and appends to the original list to comply to what appears to be implied by the original problem statement -- though the problem statement confusingly uses 'list' and 'array' interchangeably.